# Performing a Scrapy broad crawl with high concurrency and low request rate on each domain.

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make a Scrapy broad crawl. The goal is to have many concurrent crawls at different domains but at the same time crawl gently on each domain. And therefore be able to maintain a good crawling speed and keep the request frequency low on each url.

Here is the spider i use:

```
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from myproject.items import MyprojectItem

class testSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "testCrawler16"
    start_urls = [
              "http://example.com",
    ]

    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('.com','.nl','.org'),
                              allow=('.se'))

    rules = (
        Rule(extractor,callback='parse_links',follow=True),
        )

    def parse_links(self, response):
        item = MyprojectItem()
        item['url'] =response.url
        item['depth'] = response.meta['depth']
        yield item
```

And here is the settings i use:

```
BOT_NAME = 'myproject'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['myproject.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'myproject.spiders'

REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 20
RETRY_ENABLED = False
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 15
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
DEPTH_LIMIT = 10


AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
```

The problem is that after a while the crawler crawls less and less concurrently and only alternates between a few domains, sometimes only one. And therefore the Auto throttle slows down the crawl speed. How can i make the spider keep up the concurrency and have many separate connection to many domains and use the concurrency to maintain speed while keeping the request rate low at each domain?

Answer (score 4):

`AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` is not recommended for fast crawling, I would recommend setting it to `False`, and just crawling gently on your own.

The only settings you need here are `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.

set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to the value you want for crawling every request per domain, `10` for example if you want 6 requests per minute (one every `10` seconds).

set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` to 1 for respecting the previous `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` interval per domain.

set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to a high value, it could be the number of domains you are planning to crawl (or higher). This is just so it doesn't interfere with the previous settings.

Comment: Why is autothrottle not recommended for fast/broad crawls?

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a time stamp in a dict with the domain as the key and just grab the smallest number (oldest). Then either pop the URLs out of the list or make the list global and remove from the pipeline.

```
class PoliteSpider(Spider):
name = 'polite_spider'
allowed_urls = ['*']
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'pipelines.MainPipeline': 90,
    },
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 200,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 25,
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 100,
    'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 400,
    # Hides printing item dicts
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
    'REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES': 1,
    # Stops loading page after 5mb
    'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 5592405,
    # Grabs xpath before site finish loading
    'DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS': False
}

def __init__(self):
    self.links = ['www.test.com', 'www.different.org', 'www.pogostickaddict.net']
    self.domain_count = {}

def start_requests(self):
    while self.links:
        start_time = time.time()
        url = next(x for x in self.links if min(domain_count, key=domain_count.get) in x)
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True,
                                 meta={'time': time.time(), 'url': url})

        yield request

def parse(self, response):
    domain = response.url.split('//')[-1].split('/')[0]
    self.domain_count[domain] = time.time()

    pageloader = PageItemLoader(PageItem(), response=response)

    pageloader.add_xpath('search_results', '//div[1]/text()')
    self.links.remove(response.meta['url'])

    yield pageloader.load_item()
```

Small example:

```
import time
test = {'www.test.com': 1, 'www.different.org': 2, 'www.pogostickaddict.net': 3}
links = ['www.test.com/blog', 'www.different.org/login', 'www.pogostickaddict.net/store/checkout']

url = next(x for x in links if max(test, key=test.get) in x)
print(time.time())
print(links)
print(url)
links.remove(url)
print(links)
print(time.time())
```

1549868251.3280149 
['www.test.com/blog', 'www.different.org/login', 'www.pogostickaddict.net/store/checkout']
www.pogostickaddict.net/store/checkout
['www.test.com/blog', 'www.different.org/login']
1549868251.328043